# github private account and company account

Tags: github

I often saw colleagues's private account and company account both showing in the commit log. How does this happen?

for example, one has a `jack` private Github account and a company account called `workjack`, I can see the two account are push to our company private repository(in commit log).

Comment: Does your colleague work from home? Might be better off asking them though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often the case when one does not set `user.name` and `user.email` in each repo, but rather one user.name/email globally (`git config --global user.name xxx`).
Then that setting applies to *all* repos on the user's machine.

If this is done both at home (private account) and at work (work account), then commits done (and pushed) from both this places would get different user accounts associated to them, even though the repo might call for only one of those accounts to be used.